# Merge two datatables

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I have two datatables. Each has three columns, the two of them have the same name. However one column in table1 is "Desc", in table2 is named as "Descr".
How to merge them together?

Thanks.

> EDIT

The two datatables come from two datagridview.

```
                       DataRow dr = dg1.Newrow()
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
                        {
                            dr[0] = row[0];
                            dr[1] = row[1];
                            dr[2] = row[2];
                            dg1.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
```

dg1 is a datagridview. dt2 is just a datatable.

Comment: Should I loop throw each DataRow? Is there a quick way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Merge` method

You can find some sample code here along with docs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx

Note:  You may have to rename your Desc column just before you merge the tables:

```
dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Descr";
```

Comment: I got an exception:<target>.EntryDE and <source>.EntryDE have conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch.

Comment: @Love, without seeing your code and the datatable structures, I will not be able to help.  Try to include as much detail as possible in the question and you'll get better responses in less time, without people asking "What have you tried?" all the time.

Comment: Rename the column just before you merge.  dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Descr";

Comment: See my updated code, please help me to correct the error. The first datatable is not directly visible. Actually it is from a datagridview. I want to dynamically update the datagridview.

Comment: @Love - I see your update, but I don't the code that you have tried with Merge.  I also don't see the schemas.  It's difficult to help without seeing all the code.  Now that this question is resolved, you should ask a new question: How do I merge these two DataTables?  Present the code you tried, and the schemas of the datatables, along with any other code that seems relevent.

Answer (score 4):

Please use Merge method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

```
e.g. 
mergeTable = dataTable1.Copy();
mergeTable.Merge(dataTable2);
```